# Converting GPa and TPa to N/m

Tags: forces, pressure, units, dimensional-analysis

I have a problem with converting units, in some papers, ultimate tensile strength has been shown with GPa or TPa, but in some papers, it has been presented with N/m. (not newton per square meter)

As i searched, they are in different types,  but i have to fill a table that asks me to write all value of tensile strength with N/m. I could not find a way to convert them. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Odds are good that N/m is used in 2D problems, where it is assumed "per unit depth."

Comment: Which  some papers?

Comment: N/m would be the SI units for a spring constant, not an ultimate stress value.

Comment: N/m is for standard thickness of some material. Divide (or multiply) by the thickness  - in the same unit =m!

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is impossible. Pressure is force per unit area.